# While loop with ++variable

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Sorry for this easy question but I couldn't find the answer, if I got a while loop that looks like this. Does it calculate before or after the comparison?

```
a = 0;
while(a++ < 5)
{
    ....
```

When it first runs the loop will it look at it as "1 < 5" or "0 < 5". Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it out? `printf('%d', a);` in the loop and see what happens.

Comment: @MarcB: because the result of the print would not be conclusive, and even counter intuitive?

Comment: @njz: it'd print `a` as many times as the inner loop executed, which tells you when the while() condition succeeded/failed.

Comment: Or even better than trying it or asking others: get rid of the ++ entirely and write clean, readable code.

Comment: Might I suggest a simple online search for 'c operator precedence'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison is done *BEFORE* the increment, but the body of the loop sees the value *AFTER* icrementation. So in the first run you'll compare 0 < 5, but in the loop a will have the value of 1.

Comment: what if it had said ++a? Would the increment had been done before the comparison?

Comment: @Fjodor : Yes - it would then be executed before the compare, so you'd effectively have 1 < 5

Answer (score 1):

The postfix operator is applied "after".  The prefix operator is applied "before".  In the case you've provided the first time 'a' is compared it's value will equal 0

Be careful, cause you can get in trouble with these operators if not used with care.  Consider a[ix++] = a[ix] + 1;   maybe it will do what you want, maybe not ... try it

Just read the other comment ... very good point that a will take on the ++ value *insde* the loop.

Comment: No matter whether it "works" or not, `a[ix++] = a[ix] + 1` is *undefined behaviour*, and demons might fly out of your nose.

Comment: Which may are may not be what you want, depending on how one feels about nose demons :-D

Answer (score 1):

The result of the expression `a++` is the current value of `a`, so the loop will start out as `while ( 0 < 5 )`.

The result of the expression `++a` is the value of `a + 1`, so if you had written `while ( ++a < 5 )`, it would start out as `while ( 1 < 5 )`.

In both cases, `a` will be incremented by 1 as a *side effect*.  Note that the side effect does not have to be applied immediately after the expression is evaluated; the only guarantee is that it is applied before the next sequence point (in this particular case, the sequence point is at the end of the conditional expression, so the body of the loop will see the updated value of `a`).  So, if you have an expression like

```
x = a++ * ++b;
```

it will be *evaluated* as `x = a * (b + 1)`, but there's no guarantee that `a` will be incremented before `++b` has been evaluated, nor is there any guarantee that either will be incremented before the multiplication and the assignment.  The following is one of many acceptable order of operations:

1. `t1 <- b + 1`
2. `x <- a * t1`
3. `b <- b + 1`
4. `a <- a + 1`